# Restoring Time Machine backup made on a previous OS X version

Tags: macos, time-machine, restore

My macbook pro, running OS X Lion (10.7.5) got stolen last night. Luckily they didn't take my external drive, where I have a Time Machine back up of all my data, which is extremely important to me (mostly, unfinished music productions projects in Ableton)

Since new MacBooks ship with OS X Yosemite, would I able to restore my Time Machine backup on a new laptop?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the migration assistant can migrate **from** an *older* version. However it cannot migrate **from** a *newer* version.

Backup of 10.9 --> System on 10.10 works

Backup of 10.10 --> System on 10.9 does not work

Comment: And would I be able to restore to restore all my data (aplications/plugins/ music projects with their corresponding samples and vst patches) with migration assistant?
I know that with Time Machine restoring it works just fine (I had to do it once), but I never used Migration Assistant

Comment: I was referring to migration assistant

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around, your Time Machine OS has to be same or newer than whatever computer you are installing it on. I bought a 2018 laptop, running the latest OS, and was not able to restore my circa 2012 OS time machine. Apple told me that I have to buy a computer that originally came with the same OS as my time machine, or it won't work.