# Restore from Time Machine which has newer OS version

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, restore

I'm trying to restore my MacBook Pro from a Time Machine backup which has been made on El Capitan. 
After I wiped my MacBook it reinstalled the OS it came with when I bought it (Mavericks).
But after I try to restore from my Time Machine backup, it won't work. After it's done it simply does not boot.
What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to upgrade to El Capitan before I can restore successfully?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the NVRAM? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Comment: @NoahL I didn't, I'm trying to restore a second time now, will do after. I'm wondering if I need to upgrade to El Capitan first to make the restore work?

Comment: unless I am mistaken, you shouldn't have to. I regularly use time machine backups to do downgrade restores (from 10.12 to 10.11.6 for example). So I'd assume you could go both ways (I am not positive that that's true).

Comment: @NoahL good to know that it works at least downgrade wise. I need to see and wait, hopefully it works both ways.

Comment: @NoahL http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176990/restoring-time-machine-backup-made-on-a-previous-os-x-version damn :(

Comment: yes you need to make the upgrade, but it should be free and easy to do. It will just take a little bit of time.

Comment: @NoahL he's talking about the Migration Assistent though. Maybe it is different for restoring?

Comment: maybe. But you've already spent so much time, I'd suggest updating to El Capitan or Sierra and then restoring from there